# Posting photos on our DONATE/ contribution page through Civi

Tags: contributions

Is there an ideal image size for posting photos on this page? The photo that I want to post keeps getting smushed. I finally found decent dimensions but it the mobile website doesn't keep the correct dimensions.

Let me know!

Comment: Image dimensions really depend on your site's needs, theme, etc. I don't know that there is really an overall ideal image size, as that would vary greatly between sites. It sounds like maybe this is theme related, as opposed to CiviCRM related. Do you have the URL so we can look at it? It's hard to troubleshoot without it.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the best option is to give the image a width of 100% or at least use media queries to set the width at 100% for mobile